# Checking if Firebase data exists as a condition

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know this question has been asked before, but I'm unable to get my syntax correct using the others answers I found on Stack Overflow.

I have a function getUserDict that attempts to download an object from a Firebase database like this (This code is working fine):

```
function getUserDict() {
    let current_user_id = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
    return firebase.database().ref().child('profile').child(current_user_id).child('user_dict').once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
        return snapshot.val()
    })
}
```

However I'm trying to execute the code in the below try statement to check for the existence of that object, and if it doesn't exist I know the user has not yet made a profile, and want to execute the code in the catch statement like this:

```
function userLogin() {
    traceFunction()
    console.log('userLogin')
    if (checkLogin()) {
        console.log('userLogin checkLogin is true')
        hideInputText()
        left_button.style.visibility = 'hidden'
        showLogoAnimation()
        try {
            user_dict = getUserDict().then(function (user_dict) {
                console.log('userLogin user_dict is ', user_dict)
                hideLogoAnimation()
                handleWelcome(is_first_time = false)
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('userLogin unable to find user_dict, preparing needed data')
            user_dict = getQuestions().then(user_dict => createProfile(user_dict)).then(function () {
                console.log('userLogin user_dict is ', user_dict)
                hideLogoAnimation()
                handleWelcome(is_first_time = true)
            })
        }
    } else {
        console.log('userLogin checkLogin is false')
        question_text.innerText = "What's your e-mail address?"
        showInputText()
        left_button.style.visibility = 'hidden'
        right_button.innerText = 'Submit'
        right_button.onclick = userSubmitEmail
    }
}
```

As is, this code is returning user_dict is null on my console.log statement, so I'm realizing the code hangs because it gets stuck trying to download the data from Firebase instead of going to the catch statement when it fails.

If try/catch can't be used for it, what's the best way for me to check for the existence of the object? I don't want to download all of the user data to check it for security reasons of course, so I'm assuming there's a function or method of doing this properly that I'm missing?

Edit: Adding my attempt of the async/await suggestion, but the behavior and error is identical.

```
async function userLogin() {
    traceFunction()
    console.log('userLogin')
    if (checkLogin()) {
        console.log('userLogin checkLogin is true')
        hideInputText()
        left_button.style.visibility = 'hidden'
        showLogoAnimation()
        try {
            user_dict = await getUserDict();
            console.log('userLogin user_dict is ', user_dict)
            hideLogoAnimation()
            handleWelcome(is_first_time = false)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('userLogin unable to find user_dict, preparing needed data')
            user_dict = getQuestions().then(user_dict => createProfile(user_dict)).then(function () {
                console.log('userLogin user_dict is ', user_dict)
                hideLogoAnimation()
                handleWelcome(is_first_time = true)
            })
        }
    } else {
        console.log('userLogin checkLogin is false')
        question_text.innerText = "What's your e-mail address?"
        showInputText()
        left_button.style.visibility = 'hidden'
        right_button.innerText = 'Submit'
        right_button.onclick = userSubmitEmail
    }
}

async function getUserDict() {
    let current_user_id = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
    let snapshot = await firebase.database().ref().child('profile').child(current_user_id).child('user_dict').once('value')
    return snapshot.val()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by using if (snapshot.exists) as a conditional statement as shown below:

```
function userLogin() {
    traceFunction()
    console.log('userLogin')
    if (checkLogin()) {
        console.log('userLogin checkLogin is true')
        hideInputText()
        left_button.style.visibility = 'hidden'
        showLogoAnimation()
        user_dict = getUserDict()
        if (user_dict) {
            console.log('userLogin user_dict is ', user_dict)
            hideLogoAnimation()
            handleWelcome(is_first_time = false)
        } else {
            console.log('userLogin unable to find user_dict, preparing needed data')
            user_dict = getQuestions().then(user_dict => createProfile(user_dict)).then(function () {
                console.log('userLogin user_dict is ', user_dict)
                hideLogoAnimation()
                handleWelcome(is_first_time = true)
            })
        }
    }
}

function getUserDict() {
    let current_user_id = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
    let snapshot = firebase.database().ref().child('profile').child(current_user_id).child('user_dict').once('value')
    if (snapshot.exists) {
        return snapshot.val()
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have two options here that could work well for you

1. using `.catch()` in the appropriate places rather than `try/catch`

or

2. using `async/await` with `try/catch` like this:

```js
async function getUserDict() {
   let current_user_id = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
   let snapshot = await firebase.database().ref().child('profile').child(current_user_id).child('user_dict').once('value');
   return snapshot.val();
}
```

and

```js
async function userLogin() {
    ...
    if (checkLogin()) {
        ...
        try {
            user_dict = await getUserDict();
            hideLogoAnimation()
            handleWelcome(is_first_time = false)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('userLogin unable to find user_dict, preparing needed data')
            user_dict = getQuestions().then(user_dict => createProfile(user_dict)).then(function () {
                console.log('userLogin user_dict is ', user_dict)
                hideLogoAnimation()
                handleWelcome(is_first_time = true)
            })
        }
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting the exact same behavior, there's no change in the error using async/await as you suggested. I edited my original answer to show the code I'm using, is that identical to what you suggested?